UWP: Separate XAML for Xbox device
I have a UWP app which can run on both desktop and xbox device.
How can specify a different XAML for some xbox page?
Is there some kind of special folder name I can use to specify a different XAML just for the Xbox version?

A "different XAML" is just a different page. You can detect if you're running on XBox and reference the appropriate page. The effort depends on how the existing page was implemented in the first place. Unless its the "Store" images ... I think those are referenced based on size.
